# how can i get the button's command argument?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, visual-studio

Is it possible to get a button's command argument in javascript. I don't want to manipulate it, i just want to read it.

If possible - how?

Comment: Effectively you want to know the javascript you're that is executing?

Comment: Huh? I want to be able to get the command argument for a button given a client id.

Comment: "command argument" and "client id" aren't really javascript terms; do you mean "onclick" and "id"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make your own attribute and get it with standard JavaScript:

**Markup:**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" cmdname="test" CommandName="test" CommandArgument="1" 
    runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

**Script:**

```
//however you choose to get the element, jQuery...etc
document.getElementById('<%=LinkButton1.ClientID %>').cmdname
```

Comment: you are a beast!! I didn't know you can make up your own property. I've been at this for hours now!!! thanks rick!! if i could give you more points i would.

Comment: To use correct HTML5 (though it works fine in older HTML too!) you should prefix your custom attribute with `data-`. So you'd have `data-cmdname`. See http://tinyurl.com/6uycchj

Answer (score 1):

You can put command argument into some hidden field, then retrieve the value of the hidden field in javascript after page loads such as $(document).ready() in JQuery.

Comment: This is the only way.  The command argument exists only on the server side as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO if you are ONLY using javascript. **But** you could retrieve it with an ajax call to the server or using a hidden field like J.W. suggested. This property is not even accessible from themes. For more info read the documentation in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx)