# Update Panel and triggers from a repeater control

Tags: asp.net, triggers, updatepanel, repeater

Hi I found code similiar to the following online. It's seems really great for getting a button buried in a repeater control to trigger a full cycle back to the server.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
        </asp:ScriptManager> 

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
            <ContentTemplate> 
                <%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %> 
            </ContentTemplate> 
            <Triggers> 
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="HiddenButton" /> 
            </Triggers> 
        </asp:UpdatePanel> 

        <!--Make a hidden button to treat as the postback trigger--> 
        <asp:Button ID="HiddenButton" runat="server" Style="display: none" Text="HiddenButton" /> 


        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                 <!--when cick the button1, it will fire the hiddenButton--> 
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Trigger" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' OnClientClick="$get('HiddenButton').click();return false;" 
                    runat="server" /> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:Repeater>
```

It uses a hiddenButton to achieve this by hooking the click event of the original button to this one. However my addition to this was the setting of the CommandArgument for the button. I would also need it to be set for the HiddenButton.

Does anyone know a way of going about this?

Comment: I'll post this as a comment rather than an answer as I'm not sure if it'll work, but you could try [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567949/how-can-i-get-the-buttons-command-argument) of creating your own attribute and setting that.

Comment: I don't think you even need javaScript. Remove HiddenButton and <Triggers> When you click “Button" , the updatepanel will be refreshed. So do you mean a you need a `AsyncPostBackTrigger` ?

Answer (score 13):

First I will like to explain the `Disadvantage` of using the `Update Panel` using the very same example posted by you.

### Below is the Original Code

[image]

---

### Output

[image]

---

To display the 22 character string you can check how much data is being received and sent to server. Just imagine following

1. If you would consider send each request to `Database` using `Update Panel` and your `GridView` is in `Update Panel`!!!!!!
2. Suppose you would use `ViewState` data for each request and with `GridView Inside the Update Panel`.

Both the above techniques are worst as per my understanding.

---

Now I will describe you `Page Methods`

### Page Method over Update panel

`Page Methods` allow `ASP.NET AJAX` pages to directly execute a `Page’s Static Methods`, using `JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)`. Instead of posting back and then `receiving HTML markup` to completely replace our `UpdatePanel’s contents`, we can use a `Web Method` to request only the information that we’re interested.

### Sample Code

[image]
[image]

---

### Output

[image]

Hope this clearly explains the difference of usage.

---

### Answer to the original Query

You have to register the `ItemDataBound` event of the below `Repeater` and use below code for it.

### Code Behind

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
                           e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("Button1");
        btn.OnClientClick = string.Format("SubmitButton('{0}');return false;"
                                                        , HiddenButton.ClientID);

    }
}
```

---

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function SubmitButton(btn)
     {
         $("#" + btn).click(); 
     }
</script>
```

### //Alternative

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function SubmitButton(btn)
     {
         document.getElementById(btn).click(); 
     }
</script>
```

---

**[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.rendermode.aspx)**  & **[Here](http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your HiddenButton control is a server control but you are trying to access it in JQuery using it's ASP.Net ID,

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Trigger" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' OnClientClick="$get('**HiddenButton**').click();return false;" 
                runat="server" />
```

A quick way to fix it is to make a separate function,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitButton(btn)
{
     $get("#" . btn).click(); 
}
</script>
```

and change your button code to ,

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Trigger" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' 
                runat="server" />
```

In code behind, in repeater's ItemDataBound event, find the button and HiddenControl and set Button1's OnClientClick property,

```
Button1.OnClientClick= string.Format("SubmitButton('{0}');return false;",HiddenButton.ClientID);
```